# NA in legend from "Warning: NAs introduced by coercion"

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I'm trying to apply colour to my graph using the variable source from my dataset, which only has two values of 1 and 2.

Source is a character variable and when I tried to use it as is to add colour it didn't work. So I transformed it to a numeric variable then added breaks to categorize it. However, now this issue comes up.

```
a2 <- read.csv(file = "dataset.csv")

library("dplyr")
library("ggpubr")
library("ggplot2")

a2$source_numeric <- as.numeric(a2$source)

class(a2$source_numeric)

a2$source_numeric <- cut(a2$source_numeric,
                       breaks=c(0, 1.1, 2.1),
                       labels=c('Young', 'Adult'))

#Plot Graph
ggplot(data = a2, aes(x = familiar_place, y = commit3, color=source_numeric))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = source_numeric), size = 1.3)+
  ggpubr::color_palette("jco")+
  ggpubr::theme_classic2()+
  theme(legend.position ="top")+
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal")+
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(color = "Age of Voice Messaging")+ 
  xlab("Familiarity with Location")+
  ylab("Commitment to Water Conservation")+
  ggtitle("Water Conservation Commitment by Location Familiarity and \n Age of Voice Messaging")
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY1ZJ.png)

Comment: Best Guess: Check "a2$source_numeric" to see if there is an NA in the data set.  Cut will usually mark the lowest value NA, unless told otherwise.

Comment: The `"NAs introduced by coercion"` warning often arises when using `as.numeric()` on a vector with some values that can’t be coerced to numeric. So I would check `unique(a2$source)` for any values that might be causing this. If not, please share your data by copy/pasting the results of `dput(a)`.